# Tatsu: Rule Ordering

Tags: tatsu

I am playing around with Tatsu to implement a parser for a language used in the semiconductor industry. This language requires that variables be defined before usage. So for example:

```
SignalGroup { A: In; B: Out};
Pattern {
   V {A=1, B=1 }
   V {A=1, B=0 }
};
```

In this case, the SignalGroup block must come *before* the Pattern block. How do I enforce/implement this "ordering" when writing the grammer in TatSu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although for some languages it is possible to write grammars that verify if the same symbol appears on different places, the grammars usually end up being too complicated to be useful.

Compilers (translators) are usually implemented with separate lexical, syntactical, and semantic analyzer components. There are several reasons for that:

- Each component is so well focused that it is clearer and easier to write.
- Each component is very efficient
- The most common errors (which are exactly lexical, syntactical, and semantic) can be reported earlier

With those components in mind, checking if a symbol has ben previously defined belongs to the semantic (meaning) aspect of the program, and the way to check is to keep a symbol table that is filled when the *definition* parts of the input are being parsed, and queried on the *use* parts of the input are being parsed.

In **TatSu** in particular the different components are well separated, yet run in parallel. For your requirement you just need to use the simplest grammar that allows for the [semantic actions](https://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/semantics.html) that store and query the symbols. By raising `FailedSemantics` from within semantic actions, any semantic errors will be reported exactly as the lexical and syntactical ones so the user doesn't have to think about which component flagged each error.

If you use the Python parser generation in **TatSu**, the translator will generate the skeleton of a semantic actions class as part of the output.